# What if the drools rule file is red but can run? Although it can run, the object that is red can't call properties in then?

Tags: drools

What if the drools rule file is red but can run? Although it can run, the object that is red can't call properties in 'then'?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItWSb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Drools are text files. They have no colors.

Your IDE, whatever it is, appears to have a Drools plugin that affords validation. If you have valid Drools, and the plugin shows some sort of 'invalid' indication, you should file a bug with the IDE.

In terms of your actual rule, the IDE is correct because you have an invalid self-reference. You can't declare a variable and refer to that same variable *in that selfsame declaration.*

That is, this is wrong:

```
$eventA: Person(this != $eventB, $eventA.age > $eventB.age, this after[0s, 2s] $eventB) from entry-point "ATM"
                                 ^^^^^^^^
                                 You can't refer to $eventA here! It's not declared!
```

Correct syntax is this:

```
$eventA: Person(this != $eventB, age > $eventB.age, this after[0s, 2s] $eventB) from entry-point "ATM"
```

Comment: I've tried this method, but it doesn't work. I think it's a compiler problem. If I remove 'this after [0s, 2S] $eventb', I won't report an error

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't very helpful. What does that mean? Also i hope you have 2s not 2S in your actual rule.